# How do I make my AppLab app send notifications to the device?

Tags: android, notifications, code.org, app-lab

I am trying to create a daily reminder app that sends your device a daily notification with your custom reminder. However, I have not been able to figure out how to send notifications with AppLab.

I searched it up in the documentation, and there were no relevant results. I Googled it and found a 30-minute video on how to send "notifications", but I don't have time to watch it and it probably uses fake, non-system notifications anyway.

How could I achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Let's me clarify this , You have an app(AppLab) and you want to push notification base on reminder in the app right?

Comment: @Nrohpos Yes, thats exactly what I'd like to achieve.

Comment: So you need to work with Service either Work Manger.